# Decoding the process of automatic 2 windows and 1 Linux computer shutdown

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I`m trying to move software from a old machine WES(Windows embedded standard xp) to something bit modern and on WIN 7. Everything works ok expect the fact, that the OEM setup which is build from 2 windows PC and 1 Linux PC can "close" system all together just by initiating system shut down on one of them. The win PCs are on WES (XP) and the Linux is on BusyBox V1.6.1 (Build-in shell (msh))

On the OEM setup, when I close the WES PC, the command on the linux pops as $Power Off. The setup run on the following addresses:

10.10.5.40 - Linux - all the analog data from various sensors is converted to network stream
10.10.5.41 - WES Main - it`s where all the work is carried out 10.10.5.42 - WES Post - is somewhat verifier, not quite important here. So, when exiting the application on the WES Main 10.10.5.41: Everything start from the package with Len=80 (GUI signal value) initiated from the OEM computer 10.10.5.41 (new hardware does not send that and this is what I`m trying to figure out why). Followed with the what I think is reply from Linux on 10.10.5.40 package LEN=62 (RT Signal Value). Followed by the Len=38 package (DetachAll Observers). This way system is closing down on all of the 2 WES computers and the Linux is showing $ Power Off.

On the new hardware, when exiting the same application all I get is:

Package Len=38 (DetachAll Observers) followed with package Len=35 (ConnectionClose)

Any thoughts what I am potentially missing? Firewall is disabled on the Win7

I`d much appreciate any support.

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried to look through the "Task Manager" for process that would controll but cannot see any obvious processes.
I`ve looked through all the files, and could not see anything that i would be able to open with notepadd++ that would indicate the code which is included in the package LEN=80 or any other.

I am more than happy to record video of how all this work but i am not sure if it is permitable to upload here.